# How to make a consistent clicked/Intersects/contains method in SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

I have some problems with the intersection functionality in SFML when I am resizing the window. 
So I do fairly know how to detect intersections or if something is clicked and so on when the window is in the predefined size.
But when resizing the window, the golbal bounds of the shapes/sprites in sfml stay exactly the same while their presentation in the window changes.
So when I now click on something it may happen that the normal SFML contains method of an object tells me that the mouse pointer is not inside, even if it seems to be like that on the screen.

The only thing I have in mind is to have a variable (e.g sf::vector2f) that stores the current change of the window compared to the original size and then not use the mouse position relative to the current window but the (with the change multiplied) projected mouse position.

But this may not be the best solution, so I wonder if I am missing something and therefore I am asking for advice, what to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [sf::RenderWindow::mapPixelToCoords](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.0/classsf_1_1RenderTarget.php#a2b0cab0e4c6af29d4efaba149d28116d) method to find out the correct position of the mouse.

From the SFML documentation:

> Convert a point from target coordinates to world coordinates.
>
> This function finds the 2D position that matches the given pixel of
>   the render target. In other words, it does the inverse of what the
>   graphics card does, to find the initial position of a rendered pixel.
>
> Initially, both coordinate systems (world units and target pixels)
>   match perfectly. But if you define a custom view or resize your render
>   target, this assertion is not true anymore, i.e. a point located at
>   (10, 50) in your render target may map to the point (150, 75) in your
>   2D world – if the view is translated by (140, 25).
>
> For render-windows, this function is typically used to find which
>   point (or object) is located below the mouse cursor.
>
> This version uses a custom view for calculations, see the other
>   overload of the function if you want to use the current view of the
>   render target.